# Cutting a subset from middle of NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I work with raster images and the module `rasterio` to imprt them as `numpy` arrays. I would like to cut a portion of size `(1000, 1000)` out of the middle of each (to avoid the out-of-bound masks of the image).

```py
image = np.random.random_sample((2000, 2000))

s = image.shape
mid = [round(x / 2) for x in s] # middle point of both axes
margins = [[y + x for y in [-500, 500]] for x in mid] # 1000 range around every middle point
```

The result is a list of 2 lists, for the cut range on each axis. But this is where I stump: `range()` doesn't accept lists, and I'm attempting the following brute force method:

```py
cut_image = image[range(margins[0][0], margins[0][1]), range(margins[1][0], margins[1][1])]
```

**However:**

```py
cut_image.shape
## (1000,)
```

Slicing an array loses dimension information which is exactly what I don't want.
Consider me confused.
Looking for a more tasteful solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer points it out, you're not *really* slicing your array, but using indexing on it.

If you want to slice your array (and you're right, that's more elegant than using list of indices) , you'll be happier with slices. That objects represents the `start:end:step` syntax.

In your case,

```py
import numpy as np

WND = 50

image = np.random.random_sample((200, 300))

s = image.shape
mid = [round(x / 2) for x in s] # middle point of both axes
margins = [[y + x for y in [-WND, WND]] for x in mid] # 1000 range around every middle point

# array[slice(start, end)] -> array[start:end]
x_slice = slice(margins[0][0], margins[0][1])
y_slice = slice(margins[1][0], margins[1][1])

print(x_slice, y_slice)
# slice(50, 150, None) slice(100, 200, None)

cut_image = image[x_slice, y_slice]

print(cut_image.shape)
# (100,100)
```

### Indexing ?

You might wonder what was happening in your question that resulted in only 1000 elements instead of the expected 1000*1000.

Here is a simpler example of indexing with lists on different dimensions

```
# n and n2 have identical values
n = a[[i0, i1, i2],[j0, j1, j2]]
n2 = np.array([a[i0, j0], a[i1, j1], a[i2, j2]]
```

This being clarified, you'll understand that instead of taking a block matrix, **your code only returns the diagonal coefficients** of that block matrix :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that what you're doing is known as integer indexing, instead of slice indexing. The bahaviour changes and may seem counterintuitive when not acquainted with it. You can check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for more details.

Here's how you could do it with basic slicing:

```
# center coordinates of the image
x_0, y_0 = np.asarray(image.shape)//2
# slice taken from the center point
out = image[x_0-x_0//2:x_0+x_0//2, y_0-y_0//2:y_0+y_0//2]

print(out.shape)
# (1000, 1000)
```

Comment: Oh it works! But why does using `:` keep the dimension but using `range()` loses a dimension?

Comment: Because what you're doing is integer indexing, not slice indexing. The bahaviour changes. Check the docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html